# Multiple Monitors in Parallels

Tags: 22.04, parallels

I am using an Ubuntu 22.04 virtual machine in Parallels 19.2.  I have Parallels set for using all monitors in full screen, however virtual Ubuntu will only display on 1 monitor.  Is Ubuntu able to take advantage of multiple monitors in Parallels?  If so, what settings do I need to be able to use multiple monitors.